# SSDT failing to find stored procedures from SQL Server Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, service-broker

I am running into an issue with SSDT and SQL Server Service Broker. When I run SSDT updates, it is finding one of the stored procedures that get created and dropped regularly (SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure-GUID).

Is there a way to ignore these stored procedures when I run my updates so that I will not get an error thrown that the stored procedure is missing (because it has already been dropped by the broker)?

Comment: The approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17402904/#27735317) might be of help to specifically filter all drop steps of stored procedures matching this name. For inspiration from actual working code, it looks like [this](https://agilesqlclub.codeplex.com/) may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen that dependency thing before, looks pretty cool!

You can use my filter to exclude them from the deployment:

https://agilesqlclub.codeplex.com/

Probably:

/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter=IgnoreName(SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure.*)"

ed

Comment: CodePlex is shutting down, are you going to migrate this to GitHub?

Comment: Alright, I asked because all answers referring to it will also need to be updated when that happens.

Comment: Oh nooooooooooo! :) I'll get drunk one night and update them all :)